# Magento 2 composer install fails with at zendframework1

Tags: magento2, install, composer

I'm running this command to install magento 2:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition .
```

It downloads a few packages:

```
Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.0.0)
  - Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.0.0)
    Loading from cache

Created project in .
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing magento/magento-composer-installer (0.1.5)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing magento/framework (100.0.2)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing magento/language-zh_hans_cn (100.0.2)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing magento/language-pt_br (100.0.2)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing magento/language-nl_nl (100.0.2)
...
```

but then fails at `zendframework1`

Installing magento/zendframework1 (1.12.16)

```
    Downloading: 100%         
    Invalid zip file, retrying...
  - Installing magento/zendframework1 (1.12.16)
    Downloading: 100%         
    Invalid zip file, retrying...
  - Installing magento/zendframework1 (1.12.16)
    Downloading: 100%   

Failed to download magento/zendframework1 from dist: '/Users/User/sites/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/6d7139aa6e64ddb9093d21b217100f9d' is not a zip archive.
Failed to execute unzip '/Users/User/sites/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/6d7139aa6e64ddb9093d21b217100f9d' -d '/Users/User/sites/magento2/vendor/composer/99e1ac00' && chmod -R u+w '/Users/User/sites/magento2/vendor/composer/99e1ac00'

  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /Users/User/sites/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/6d7139aa6e64ddb9093d21b217100f9d or
        /Users/User/sites/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/6d7139aa6e64ddb9093d21b217100f9d.zip, and cannot find /Users/User/sites/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/6d7139aa6e64ddb9093d21b217100f9d.ZIP, period.
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing magento/zendframework1 (1.12.16)
    Cloning c9d607bfd9454bc18b9deff737ccd5d044e2ab10



  [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]                                                                                                                                      
  The process "git clone --no-checkout 'git://github.com/magento/zf1.git' '/Users/User/sites/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1' && cd '/Users/User/sites/magento2/vendor/magento/zendfram  
  ework1' && git remote add composer 'git://github.com/magento/zf1.git' && git fetch composer" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Specify your github token during request to bypass [rate limits](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#api-rate-limit-and-oauth-tokens) of github.

Alternatively you may do this with `--prefer-source` option (this will be slower):

`composer create-project --prefer-source --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition .`

Answer (score 0):

You need specify folder into download or not specify. You do not use dot, because is not working with dot, to end of command
Run this command for specify folder:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento
```

Run this for not spacify and it creates a new folder:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition
```